# Does the -add method of an NSArrayController append the object to the end of the content array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarraycontroller

Adding an object to an `NSMutableArray` appends the very object to the end of that array. Can we assume that the same happens when adding an object to an `NSArrayController` backed by an `NSMutableArray`?

The reason I ask is that I add objects with a date property. If I remove any objects from the array, I first remove the oldest ones. If objects are always added to the end, the first objects in the array are the oldest ones.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Doesn't specify.

Comment: You can't assume that the object is added to the end.